# How to calculate the period of a pendulum

Tags: c, physics, numerical-methods, ode

The task is to calculate the period of a pendulum. One of my values is blowing up as it approaches t=0, which is confusing me a lot. I also don't know if any of my values are correct.

The following is my interpolation function, Interp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double Interp(double x_1, double y_1, double x_2, double y_2, double x){
        double k,y,b;
        k=(y_2-y_1)/(x_2-x_1);
        b=y_2-(k*x_2);
        y=k*x+b;
        return(y);       
}
```

This function takes two x values and interpolates a y value. I call this function in my program to find the period.

The following is the code to find the period of the pendulum:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double Interp();

int main(){
        int i,j;
        double  x,v,dv,dt,dx,t,n;
        double  oldt, x1, diff, xnext, crosst1, crosst2, sol;
        FILE *fp;
        fp=fopen("Pendulum.out","w");
        dt=(6*M_PI)/40000;
        v=0; j=0;

        for(n=0;n<M_PI;n+=0.05){
                x=n;
                for(i=0;i<50000;i++){
                        t=i*dt;
                        dv=(-sin(x)*dt);
                        dx=v*dt;
                        v=v+dv;
                        oldt=(i-1)*dt;
                        x1=x;
                        x=x+dx;
                        xnext=x;

                        if(j==1 && x1>0 && xnext<0) {
                                crosst2=Interp(x1, oldt, xnext,t, 0);
                                j++;
                        }

                        if(j==0 && x1>0 && xnext<0) {
                                crosst1=Interp(x1, oldt, xnext,t, 0);
                                j++;
                        }
                }

                sol=crosst2-crosst1;
                fprintf(fp,"%lf\t%lf\n", n, sol);
                v=0;
                j=0;
                i=0;
        }

        fclose(fp);

}
```

This program is supposed to find the period by recording when the pendulum crosses some point for the first time, and then again for the second time. Then, finding the difference will give us the period.

This is a sample of the resulting output.

```
0.000000        -0.000000
0.050000        inf 
0.100000        6.287124
0.150000        6.321593
0.200000        6.321101
0.250000        6.313769
0.300000        6.358041
0.350000        6.335938
```

These values seem reasonable (ish) to me, but I can't figure out why it blows up to infinity at n=0.05. I'm also not entirely sure how to check if my results are correct.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: What is M_PI value? I defined it as 3.1428 and executed in https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler . I am getting 6.281470 when n is 0.5.

Comment: I used #include <math.h>, so M_PI should be defined as 3.14159265358979323846.

Comment: In that compiler, looks like M_PI is not defined. However, i defined M_PI as 3.14159265358979323846 and rerun. Still getting 6.284170 for n=0.5. I would recommend you to print intermediate values in your code and find out what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

At least this problem

`sol=crosst2-crosst1;` may use `crosst2, crosst1` without one or both of them ever set leading to *undefined behavior*.

Best to initialize them or not perform the subtraction until both are set.

---

For further investigation, recommend below: GTG.

```
fprintf(fp, "%.17g %.17g %lf\t%lf\n", crosst1, crosst2, n, sol);
```

Note: I used `#define M_PI 3.1415926535897932384626433832795`